# How to disable task scheduler conditions?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

so yeah I want to do what title says basically. I'm on my laptop and found out that Task Scheduler sets conditions automatically to run **only** when laptop is in the charging. How do I turn conditions off so they will normally run even if my laptop is not charging via cmd?

Comment: Are you talking about specific tasks, or all tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If PowerShell also suits your demands, you can take some commands of the [ScheduledTasks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/?view=windowsserver2019-ps) Module. All of the commands below should be run in an elevated PowerShell.

First, you need to set your Tasksettings. The one that you need (I think) is to allow on battery start, and don't stop the task if you go on battery:

```
$TaskSettings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries
```

Then you need to set those settings to the task:

```
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName MyTaskName -Settings $TaskSettings
```

You can check your settings via:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName MyTaskName | Select -expand Settings


AllowDemandStart                : True
AllowHardTerminate              : True
Compatibility                   : Win7
DeleteExpiredTaskAfter          :
DisallowStartIfOnBatteries      : False
Enabled                         : True
ExecutionTimeLimit              : PT72H
Hidden                          : False
IdleSettings                    : MSFT_TaskIdleSettings
MultipleInstances               : IgnoreNew
NetworkSettings                 : MSFT_TaskNetworkSettings
Priority                        : 7
RestartCount                    : 0
RestartInterval                 :
RunOnlyIfIdle                   : False
RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable       : False
StartWhenAvailable              : False
StopIfGoingOnBatteries          : False
WakeToRun                       : False
DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession : False
UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine      : True
MaintenanceSettings             :
volatile                        : False
PSComputerName                  :
```

if you want to do this for all your tasks, you can do it like so - However, I would only advise you to change the task settings of the tasks you really want to:

```
$TaskSettings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries

Get-ScheduledTask | ForEach-Object {
    Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName $_.TaskName -Settings $TaskSettings
}
```

Mind that you will overwrite all current Tasksettings with the ones you set via `New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet`

Check out all the tasksettings you can set through PowerShell [in the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasksettingsset?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

Comment: Yeah powershell also meets my demands. Thanks for this beautiful answer.